# Command line build using VS 2015 is 2 to 3 times slower than VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Our Gated CheckIn build uses devenv command line build. Let us not delve into why - we think we have good reasons - a different discussion.

Anyway, I upgraded it to VS 2015 from VS 2012 and uninstalled the latter.

Now the same code base built using the same msbuild targets file (which invokes devenv) runs 2 to 3 times slower!

VS 2015 has no extra plugins installed. Version control integration is disabled. Not signed in to msdn.

I realise this is not a lot and would happily provide more details.

Looking for advice (please do not advise to switch to msbuild for code compilation).

**EDIT 1**

This is a machine dedicated to the Gated Check-In build. It has the same setup as before with regards to the Anti Virus (should be disabled). The only change - instead of VS 2012 there is now VS 2015.

I explicitly call devenv.com, not devenv.exe.

devenv internally invokes msbuild, but on the per project level. It uses its own logic to decide whether a project needs to be built and in what order should they be built. But once the decision is made, it is msbuild that actually builds it. The logging is set from the VS GUI (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run) and affects all the devenv instances, since it is written to the registry (and is later used to determine the value of the msbuild /verbose parameter)

Comment: I'm not familiar with devenv build - does it offer logging comparable to msbuild so could identify possibly particularly slow parts of you process?

Comment: Don't really have a solution for you but following as this has me curious. Is this happening on all machines that try to build or just yours? Have you checked to make sure that your antivirus isn't trying to do an active scan on the build process like mentioned here: http://ardalis.com/speed-up-visual-studio-build-times

Comment: VS2012 was the last "good" VS version before DivDev switched to agile.  Expecting similar perf from VS2015 is wishful thinking, too many wiz-bang features get in the way.  Only advice is to make sure you use devenv.com instead of devenv.exe.